# Why doesn't compound literals assignment work without a typecast

Tags: c, c99, compound-literals

I have a question about literals in C.

```
int a;
//a is an integer that is assigned an integer literal 414
a = 414;

float b;
//b is a float that is assigned a float literal of 3.14
b = 3.14;

struct point {
    int x,y;
};

struct point b;
//{5,6} is a compound literal that is assigned to a struture.
b = {5,6}; //doesn't work.

b = (struct point){5,6}; //works.
```

That doesn't seem to work without a typecast? What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(struct point){5,6}` as a whole is a compound literal.

> #### C11 §6.5.2.5 *Compound literals*
>
> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a brace enclosed
> list of initializers is a compound literal.

Comment: Since the type can be inferrd from the decleration of point b before the initialization,why doesn't it work?

Comment: @liv2hak `(struct point)` is not a cast, it's part of the compound literal.

Comment: Can't that be infered from the Symbol Table?

Comment: @liv2hak: It cannot be inferred. `{5,6}` could be an `int[2]`, or a `struct { char a, b; }`, ...